# How can I debug email sending within my Symfony2 application?

Tags: php, email, symfony

I am using the FOSUser bundle within my Symfony2 application. I am trying to get the email functionality working but can't get any emails to send successfully.

My development environment is a Ubuntu virtual machine. I tried to use my Gmail account details as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html). I also checked the error logs but nothing regarding the email  sending is logged.

I attempted to send a test email using a test controller;

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class TestEmailController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmailAction()
    {
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom('send@example.com')
            ->setTo('me@myemailaddress.com') // use a valid email in actual code...
            ->setBody('yo, wassup!');
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

        return $this->render('SysDevPunctualityBundle:TestEmail:sendEmail.html.twig', array(
                // ...
        ));    
    }

}
```

However this triggers an error with Symfony's web profiler toolbar and I get the following message; "Token "3c494e" was not found in the database."

After some digging around I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000763/symfony2-swiftmailer-not-sending) I followed the suggestion of removing the spool option and also added a 'from_email' option. This made a difference, I am now getting a timeout error:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

My guess is that the firewall is blocking the request, I don't know how to find out for sure.

Appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: just in case check your parameter registration: -> confirmation: -> enabled: is set to true and not false. in app/config.yml

Comment: Yep, I've had this set to true, like so; `registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true

Comment: Did you try to send a test mail within a controller ?

Comment: @YannEugoné Yep, updated my question with the snippet I used.

Comment: Sorry about that, but I can't see where is the problem

Comment: This seems out of the scope of a programming problem. Try telnetting directly into `smtp.gmail.com` from the server to be sure you're being blocked, though

Comment: Connecting via Telnet also results in a 'Connection timed out' message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the source of the problem was that my work firewall was blocking access to the Gmail SMTP server. I switched to another SMTP server (set up by our IT department) and email sending now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check these two links from the cookbook, to find out how to handle emails while developing: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/dev_environment.html & http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html